# Javascript - Determine if array should have index set, a new index added, or an existing index set to 0

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm  trying to update an array periodically from an API.

Essentially I have my existing array (what was kept from before the update), and then the new array which I am comparing it to, from the API.

What I want to achieve is, the existing array being either updated with new product information, given a new product, the existing product information changing if it has changed based on the API, and if an existing product no longer exists the stock of it being set to 0.

Taking from this thread here - https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/196692/determine-whether-to-push-or-update-object-in-array-based-on-unique-id

```
   var myData = [
    { product: "Ford", profit: 1000, Stock: "1"},
    { product: "Honda", profit: 1000, Stock: "1"},
];

var APIData = [
    { product: "Ford", profit: 9000, Stock: "1"},
    { product: "Toyota", profit: 1500, Stock: "1"},
];

function compareObjects(obj1, obj2) {
    let obj1Keys = [], obj1Values = [], obj2Keys = [], obj2Values = [];

    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj1)) obj1Keys.push(key) / obj1Values.push(value);
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj2)) obj2Keys.push(key) / obj2Values.push(value);

    if (obj1Keys.length !== obj2Keys.length) return false;
    for (const key of obj1Keys) {
        if (!obj2Keys.includes(key)) return false;
    }

    for (const value of obj1Values) {
        if (!obj2Values.includes(value)) return false;
    }

    return true;

};

function pushToArray(oldArray, newArray) {
    // first we create a new Array of the existing IDS.
    const newArrayIDS = newArray.map(obj => obj.product);
    // just creating a new array to return when everything is finished
    let newArrayToBeCreated = [];
    // for...loop between the oldArray (your array) 
    for (const oldObject of oldArray) {
        // if the object of the oldArray doesn't have an ID on the API, it will be setted to zero
        if (!newArrayIDS.includes(oldObject.product)) {
            console.log(`Finishing the stock of: ${oldObject.product}`);
            oldObject.Stock = "0";
            newArrayToBeCreated.push(oldObject);
        } else {
            newArray.map(object => {
                // try to found an element by ID 
                let found = oldArray.find(o => o.product === object.product);
                // if the object had found and they are different, just update.
                if (found && compareObjects(found, object) == false) {
                    console.log(`Updating the object: ${found.product}`)
                    found = object;
                    newArrayToBeCreated.push(found);
                } else {
                    newArrayToBeCreated.push(object);
                    console.log(`Adding the object: ${object.product}`);
                };
            });
        }
    }
    return newArrayToBeCreated;
};


/*
Updating the object: Ford
Adding the object: Toyota
Finishing the stock of: Honda
[
  { product: 'Ford', profit: 9000, Stock: '1', id: 1 },
  { product: 'Toyota', profit: 1500, Stock: '1', id: 3 },
  { product: 'Honda', profit: 1000, Stock: '0', id: 2 }
]
*/
console.log(pushToArray(myData, APIData));
```

So -> I think the above code will work just for adding new information and updating old, when there is information that was there but isn't now, I'm unsure how to proceed.

Appreciate your help :)

Comment: Where did you define `arr`?

Comment: `newArray` is not an array, it's missing the `[]` around it.

Comment: my bad, I shall reformat

Comment: hope that is okay

Comment: None of your objects have `id` properties.

Comment: Good point - I'll change it to product lol

Comment: Is your main question about how to remove the objects from `oldArray` that aren't in `newArray`?

Comment: It's how to update the old array, then include any new products, then for any products that are not in the new array but were in the old to set the old array stock value to 0

Comment: It's basically the opposite of how you added new products to the array. Make a list of all the new IDs, then loop through the old array. Check if the ID is in the new array. If it isn't, set the value to 0.

Comment: Good point. I'm trying to work through that logic now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code:

```js
const oldArray = [{
  product: "Ford",
  profit: 1000,
  Stock: "1",
  id: 1

},
{
  product: "Honda",
  profit: 1000,
  Stock: "1",
  id: 3
}
];

const newArray = [{
  product: "Ford",
  profit: 9000,
  Stock: "1",
  id: 3
},
{
  product: "Toyota",
  profit: 1500,
  Stock: "1",
  id: 4
}
];


function pushToArray(existingArr, incomingArr) {
console.log('......');
  incomingArr.forEach((obj) => {
    const i = existingArr.findIndex(a => {
     return a.product === obj.product
    });
    if (i > -1) {
      console.log(obj);
      existingArr[i] = obj;
    } else {
      existingArr.push(obj);
    }
  });
  console.log(existingArr)

}

pushToArray(oldArray, newArray);
```

Comment: There are no `id` properties in the objects.

Comment: You shouldn't have `{}` around `a.id === obj.id`.

Comment: Sorry I haven't seen the array. Added the id's. You can modify it as per your need.

Comment: Thanks - modifying it now. Changing ID to Product, it doesn't work unfortunately. Also, when the new array doesn't have a value in it, need the old product name to have the stock value switched to 0

Comment: This should work. Remember if you are using {} brackets you have to use return keyword. if you use without the {} you don't need to return it.
x.findIndex(a => a.product === b.product); // If you use fat arrow without {} you don't need to return anything
x.findIndex(a=> { return a.product === b.product; } // in this case you have to return

Answer (score 1):

So.. I don't know if I understood it correctly, because english is not my main language.
Short I got three things.

1. If your element from your array can not be found in the API by the ID, the stock will be changed to 0.
2. If the element from your array is different from the API, it will be changed by the API value.
3. If the element from the API can not be found in your array of elements, it will be pushed to your array.

```
var myData = [
    { product: "Ford", profit: 1000, Stock: "1", id: 1 },
    { product: "Honda", profit: 1000, Stock: "1", id: 2 },
];

var APIData = [
    { product: "Ford", profit: 9000, Stock: "1", id: 1 },
    { product: "Toyota", profit: 1500, Stock: "1", id: 3 },
];

function compareObjects(obj1, obj2) {
    let obj1Keys = [], obj1Values = [], obj2Keys = [], obj2Values = [];

    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj1)) obj1Keys.push(key) / obj1Values.push(value);
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj2)) obj2Keys.push(key) / obj2Values.push(value);

    if (obj1Keys.length !== obj2Keys.length) return false;
    for (const key of obj1Keys) {
        if (!obj2Keys.includes(key)) return false;
    }

    for (const value of obj1Values) {
        if (!obj2Values.includes(value)) return false;
    }

    return true;

};

function pushToArray(oldArray, newArray) {
    // first we create a new Array of the existing IDS.
    const newArrayIDS = newArray.map(obj => obj.id);
    // just creating a new array to return when everything is finished
    let newArrayToBeCreated = [];
    // for...loop between the oldArray (your array) 
    for (const oldObject of oldArray) {
        // if the object of the oldArray doesn't have an ID on the API, it will be setted to zero
        if (!newArrayIDS.includes(oldObject.id)) {
            console.log(`Finishing the stock of: ${oldObject.product}`);
            oldObject.Stock = "0";
            newArrayToBeCreated.push(oldObject);
        } else {
            newArray.map(object => {
                // try to found an element by ID 
                let found = oldArray.find(o => o.id === object.id);
                // if the object had found and they are different, just update.
                if (found && compareObjects(found, object) == false) {
                    console.log(`Updating the object: ${found.product}`)
                    found = object;
                    newArrayToBeCreated.push(found);
                } else {
                    newArrayToBeCreated.push(object);
                    console.log(`Adding the object: ${object.product}`);
                };
            });
        }
    }
    return newArrayToBeCreated;
};

/*
Updating the object: Ford
Adding the object: Toyota
Finishing the stock of: Honda
[
  { product: 'Ford', profit: 9000, Stock: '1', id: 1 },
  { product: 'Toyota', profit: 1500, Stock: '1', id: 3 },
  { product: 'Honda', profit: 1000, Stock: '0', id: 2 }
]
*/
console.log(pushToArray(myData, APIData));
```

Edited to work with the product name:

```
var myData = [
    { product: "Ford", profit: 1000, Stock: "1" },
    { product: "Honda", profit: 1000, Stock: "1"},
];

var APIData = [
    { product: "Ford", profit: 9000, Stock: "1" },
    { product: "Toyota", profit: 1500, Stock: "1" },
];


function compareObjects(obj1, obj2) {
    let obj1Keys = [], obj1Values = [], obj2Keys = [], obj2Values = [];

    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj1)) obj1Keys.push(key.toLowerCase()) / obj1Values.push(value);
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj2)) obj2Keys.push(key.toLowerCase()) / obj2Values.push(value);

    if (obj1Keys.length !== obj2Keys.length) return false;
    for (const key of obj1Keys) {
        if (!obj2Keys.includes(key)) return false;
    }

    for (const value of obj1Values) {
        if (!obj2Values.includes(value)) return false;
    }

    return true;

}

function pushToArray(oldArray, newArray) {

    const newArrayPRODUCTS = newArray.map(obj => obj.product.toLowerCase());

    let newArrayToBeCreated = [];

    for (const oldObject of oldArray) {
        if (!newArrayPRODUCTS.includes(oldObject.product.toLowerCase())) {
            console.log(`Finishing the stock of: ${oldObject.product}`);
            oldObject.Stock = "0";
            newArrayToBeCreated.push(oldObject);
        } else {
            newArray.map(object => {
                let found = oldArray.find(o => o.product.toLowerCase() === object.product.toLowerCase());
                if (found && compareObjects(found, object) == false) {
                    console.log(`Updating the object: ${found.product}`)
                    found = object;
                    newArrayToBeCreated.push(found);
                } else {
                    newArrayToBeCreated.push(object);
                    console.log(`Adding the object: ${object.product}`);
                };
            });
        }
    }
    return newArrayToBeCreated;
};


console.log(pushToArray(myData, APIData));
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. I think this is a pretty good answer where you explain what you're doing in the commments of the code. I do think it could be improved by providing some general text explanation of the approach. Remember Stack Overflow shouldn't really be a 'we provide free code for you' type place - rather we should be providing general educational resoruces.

Comment: Amazing Work. The only issue is there is no ID key, is it possible to use the product string instead?

Comment: @MichaelHolborn just changed the `.id` into `.product` and also, checking them as lowerCase (I also changed it in the compareObjects function), you can remove it, I think it will work but it will update if the product name is different even by the writing case.

Comment: I think there is some sort of error with this code, it is breaking for some reason

Comment: This code has an error in it, where the else statement is creating a loop that creates massive arrays, fyi.